# Attempted to call an undefined method named "filter" of class "DOMElement"

Tags: php, goutte, domcrawler

```
$goutte = new GoutteClient();
$crawler = $goutte->request('GET', 'https://www.website.com');
$reviewContent = $crawler->filter('.review-content');
$rows = $reviewContent->filter('.row');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $col1 = $row->filter('.col-md-3');
    $col2 = $row->filter('.col-md-9');
}
```

Giving the error on `$col1`

I can get it working using this but you can't use `break` as it's not a real `for loop`

```
$crawler->filter('.row')->each(function (Crawler $row, $i) {
    $col1 = $row->filter('.col-md-3');
    $col2 = $row->filter('.col-md-9');
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: @raina77ow Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: Yes, if it works; can't check it here, sadly. )

Comment: @raina77ow. Your comment works perfectly, and just saved my posterior. If it were an answer, I could mark it!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Crawler` instances (stored in `$rows`, `$reviewContent` etc.) are iterated over their DOMElement contents. You can create a new `Crawler` instance within each loop step from that `DOMElement`, like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $domRow) {
  $row = new Crawler($domRow);
  // proceed as in the original code
}
```